# Custom conversion service not used for data binding

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Using Spring 3.0.5 (spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar) I configured a custom converter and added it to the `conversionService`, like this:

```xml
<bean id="conversionService"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.example.impl.StringToMYTypeConverter" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This works fine in the spring-jdbc with `BeanPropertyRowMapper` (I have to add the `conversionService` to it by `setConversionService()`).

But for controllers it does not work.

I tried adding

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />
```

But it makes no difference.

Apparently, controller/binders use a separate instance of `conversionService`, as shown by this code:

```java
@Controller
public class MyController
{

    @Autowired
    private ConversionService conversionService;

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder)
    {
        System.out.println("conversionService="+conversionService.getClass());
        System.out.println("conversionService="+conversionService);
        System.out.println("binder.getConversionService="+binder.getConversionService().getClass());
        System.out.println("binder.getConversionService="+binder.getConversionService());
    }
```

The autowired object is of type `org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService` while the binder.conversionService is of type `org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService`.
The second line of output confirms that the first bean contains my custom converter, while the second one does not.

Changing the bean class in the XML above to `org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean` does not help either.

The question is: how to add my converter (StringToMYTypeConverter) to be used by (all, not just by one) controllers?

I tried to implement my converter as a `ProperytEditor` which works if I add it to the binder in the initBinder() method (via `binder.registerCustomEditor(MYType.class, new org.example.impl.StringToMYTypeConverter());`). Is there a way to add it to all binders/controllers in one place? That would be an acceptable solution.

**Note:** Most documentation and web content suggests that the above should work, but it doesn't. Maybe there is some small detail that I must change. Maybe tracing execution in debugger will give a clue.

Comment: Spring 3.0.5 (!?) or Spring **boot** 3.0.5?

Comment: @DirkDeyne "classic" Spring, not boot.

Comment: there are ways to add formatter and it was used by json formatters I remember, I do not remember using them in jdbc, sorry last time I touch spring 4(3 maybe 8 years ago maybe more) around 2-3 years ago, can you share a [small reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to dig deeper ?

Answer (score -1):

In Spring 3.0.5, registering custom converters for use in controllers can be a bit tricky, especially when dealing with the `ConversionService` used by Spring MVC. One workaround for this issue is to create a custom `WebBindingInitializer` and configure it to register your custom converters for all controllers. Here's how you can do it:

First, create a class that implements `WebBindingInitializer` and register your custom converters in its `initBinder()` method:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebBindingInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;

public class CustomWebBindingInitializer implements WebBindingInitializer {

    private ConversionService conversionService;

    public void setConversionService(ConversionService conversionService) {
        this.conversionService = conversionService;
    }

    @Override
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest request) {
        binder.setConversionService(conversionService);
        // Register your custom converters here
        binder.registerCustomEditor(MYType.class, new StringToMYTypeConverter());
    }
}
```

Then, in your Spring XML configuration, define this custom initializer and configure it to use your `ConversionService`:

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.example.impl.StringToMYTypeConverter" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="webBindingInitializer" class="com.example.CustomWebBindingInitializer">
    <property name="conversionService" ref="conversionService" />
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver">
            <property name="customArgumentResolver">
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver"/>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    <mvc:web-binding-initializer bean-ref="webBindingInitializer"/>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

In this configuration:

- `CustomWebBindingInitializer` is configured to use your `ConversionService` and register your custom converters.
- `<mvc:annotation-driven>` element is used to enable Spring MVC annotations. Inside it, `<mvc:web-binding-initializer>` configures the `WebBindingInitializer` bean to be used by Spring MVC. We set it to use our custom initializer.

With this setup, your custom converters should be applied to all controllers without needing to explicitly define them in each controller.